# Run composer dump-autolaod in php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I add service provider dynamically in my project and I need run `composer dump-autoload`.
 But it use system funtion
`system('composer dump-autoload');` and I am not have system ,exce ,... permission on my host. What am I do?
Can I add my service provider manually to composer.
I add to `autoload_classmap.php` and `autoload_psr4.php` but I have service provider error

Comment: don't you have ssh access to your server?

Comment: No I want use on my code

Comment: Well you dont have access, ask your host for access?

Comment: You need permissions at least for executing composer and reading and writing the vendor/ folder on your www-data user (by default)

Comment: it is share host and did not access to me

Answer (score 2):

you should change PHP.ini configuration on your server :

Open a terminal or login to your server over the ssh session. Open php.ini file:

```
# vi /etc/php.ini

Find disable_functions and set new list as follows:

disable_functions =exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source
```

Then you can remove, for example system or exec from the list

Save and close the file. Restart the httpd server by tying the following

```
command:
# service http restart
```

Also you can probably use ini_set in your php code.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I dont have access.

Comment: he doesn't have ssh.

Comment: Based on your hosting service there are some ways to have access to PHP.ini, for example your can have your local php.ini by htaccess file. However, I suggest you to ask about this way with the support of your hosting service... you can also take a look at here http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/update-local-php-settings

Comment: I do not use system , exce ,... for security

Answer (score 2):

You can try calling the following from your code:

```
Artisan::call('optimize');
```

It [does the same things](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/OptimizeCommand.php) as `composer dump-autoload`, but using an Artisan command.

Remember to add `use Artisan` to the top of your class.

Answer (score 1):

Try the php `exec` function.

```
exec('composer dump');
```

Hope this works!

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: I dont have access

Comment: you don't need for this. just put it in your code where you were putting the `system` call.

Comment: I do not use system , exce ,... for security